# Enforce further constraints on xsd:any?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XSD 1.0 sequence that defines a set of elements, some of which may be optional but none of which can occur more than once, and which also ends with an `<xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>` tag in order to enable users to add their own data elements in the easiest possible way when programmatically exporting conforming XML (i.e. ideally without requiring them to define their own namespace/XSD).

When processing XML that users generate, I will ignore any custom elements that they add via the `<any>` tag, but I want to to know if there is a way to enforce uniqueness of element names so that I can be sure that they're not putting in duplicates of elements defined in the sequence with `maxOccurs=1`?

Here is a sample xsd (interactive version [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=1512c1d0-652c-4bb6-b99c-8afd1b697758-xsdvalidation#.Vxf9bKLzkY0)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="testxsd" targetNamespace="testxsd" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="XSDSequence">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="itemA" type="xsd:string"
                             minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="itemB" type="xsd:string"
                             minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:element name="itemC" type="xsd:string"
                             minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xsd:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                         namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>  
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and here is a sample XML that passes XSD validation but which I would like to error out on due to the duplicated `<itemA>` at the end:

```
<XSDSequence xmlns="testxsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <itemA>foo</itemA>
    <itemC>bar</itemC>
    <randomElement>this is ok</randomElement>
    <itemA>I want this second itemA to cause an error</itemA>
</XSDSequence>
```

(Note that capturing data items via attributes rather than elements is ***not*** something that I want to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in XSD 1.0, once you've allowed *any* element, you can't specify further constraints beyond those afforded by `minOccurs`, `maxOccurs`, `namespace`, and `processContents`.

In XSD 1.1, you can also make `xsd:assertions` against the `xsd:any` elements; you'd be able to express your constraint with an assertion.  [**Update**: Don't miss [@C. M. Sperberg-McQueen's simpler idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36757756/290085) for XSD 1.1:  `xsd:any/@notQName="itemA itemB itemC"`]

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was more than likely to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the simplest way to ensure that the elements `itemA`, `itemB`, and `itemC` are not repeated is to use `namespace="##other"` instead of `namespace="##any"`.  (This assumes that elements in the namespace `testxsd` other than those three will not need to appear here.)

Or move to XSD 1.1 and add the attribute `notQName="itemA itemB itemC"`.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like in XSD 1.1 that notQName="##definedSibling" does exactly what I want. It's a shame that supporting XSD 1.1 when dealing with a diverse range of consumers is such a non-starter. The whole point of using XML/XSD as a data transmission format is that it's almost universally supported and XSD 1.1 support has been taking off at a snail's pace.