# XSD for complex element with any name but known structure

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

For example, if we have a file looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cars>
    <Audi>
        <PlateNumber>9488</PlateNumber>
        <Color>blue</Color>
    </Audi>
    <BMW>
        <PlateNumber>12345</PlateNumber>
        <Color>red</Color>
    </BMW>
</Cars>
```

Where the elements inside the element `Cars` can have ***any*** name, but they ***always*** have the same child nodes, `PlateNumber` and `Color`. Is something like this possible to define in a schema?

Answer (score 2):

XSD constraints are heavily anchored on XML component (element and attribute) names.  There is a provision to allow *any* element to be at a given location via `xs:any`, but once employed, there are [very limited ways to add further constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756275/enforce-further-constraints-on-xsdany).

Consider adjusting your design to adhere to the general principle of using similar names for similar things:

```
<Cars>
    <Car>
        <Make>Audi</Make>
        <PlateNumber>9488</PlateNumber>
        <Color>blue</Color>
    </Car>
    <Car>
        <Make>BMW</Make>
        <PlateNumber>12345</PlateNumber>
        <Color>red</Color>
    </Car>
</Cars>
```

Then you'll have no problem expressing the commonality between `Car` elements.

**Alternative approach:** [XSD element substitution group example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868769/xsd-element-substitution-group-example)